# Strange effect of adding resistor to the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, zener, avalanche-breakdown

Here is the circuit:

[image]
And this is the simulation settings:
[image]

Because D1N4468 is 13V Zener diode, the temperature coefficient is positive and so the breakdown voltage should increase as temperature increases. Here is the result of simulation for the breakdown region:
[image]

The curves with the label triangle and square correspond to the maximum and minimum temperature respectively. So why this happens? Weirdly if we remove the resistor, the curves would be as we expected and the breakdown voltage increases with temperature.
[image]
It seems that at some point curves intersect and then continue. This didn't happen when there was a resistor.

There is another question related to this. Is it true that for all Zener diodes breakdown voltage increases as temperature increases? I know there are there are two possible mechanisms for pn junction breakdown. Zener effect dominates in low voltages with negative temperature coefficient while avalanche dominates in high voltages with positive temperature coefficient. So I think for low voltage Zener diode TC should be negative and TC be positive for high voltage Zener diode but I don't know whether it's true or not.

Comment: With the resistor, you have currents in microamps.  Without the resistor the currents are in milliamps.

Comment: @PeterBennett Is it possible to write the equation for this circuit and see how resistor affects the characteristic of the Zener diode?

Comment: @S.H.W Zener and avalanche diodes are complicated. So having an equation is more about what you are willing to ignore. Perhaps the simplest fuller model, that would work well over a wide range, would include three diodes and a couple of voltage sources. These would cover the soft region, with currents well below the specified operating conditions; the full zener region, with currents appropriate for the operating region; and the forward conduction region, which handles the rest. Capacitance can vary widely and this is enough to handle that. If you only want the full region, though, then yes.

Comment: @jonk Okay, what we can say about TC of Zener diodes generally?

Comment: From my youth I seem to remember reading that the temperature coefficient decreased and went negative at reducing Zener voltage and that it was fairly flat at about 5 V. Is my memory and understanding correct?

Comment: @Transistor I think you're right but I'm not sure either and that is the reason why I asked the question.

Comment: @S.H.W See: [Vishay](http://www.vishay.com/docs/49494/49494.pdf).

Comment: @jonk Very useful, thanks. So by Zener diode we mean Vz<6 certainly? I think sometimes it means both types.

Comment: @S.H.W For a long time, I had no idea about the differences and lumped them all into the same idea. Anyway, you probably now know why the zener diodes with lower temperature coefficients are those nearer 6 V, as they co-mingle both behaviors.